# Show picture from ftp server inside of website

Tags: php, html, apache, ubuntu, ftp

I am having immense trouble trying to show a picture I have on my FTP-Server inside another website. What I've been trying so far, is to show the image inside of an iFrame. My code is the following:

```
<body>

<?php
$pic = file_get_contents('ftp://username:password@servername.net/image.jpg');
echo "<iframe src=". $pic . "> </iframe>";
?>
</body>
```

This is basically the code that seemed to work for other users when this question was asked, but instead for me it shows an iframe with the following message:

> Not Found

> The requested URL was not found on this server.
> Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at servername.net Port 1234

I really do not know what to try anymore, since I've tried pretty much every solution I found, so I hope one of you has any idea how to help me.

Comment: Well $pic is likely to contain file data, not a URL. Have you inspected the generated HTML which is output by the above code?

Comment: I guess that's why he tried with an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

The $pic contains the image data. So you need to encode it as an image. **This option could slow down older browsers.**

You should display the image in  tag. You can combine HTML and PHP better:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;Base64,<?=base64_encode(file_get_contents('ftp://username:password@servername.net/image.jpg'));?>">
```

**If the image is not available for you maybe try to clear your browser cache.** If you add a random parameter to the url it will be updated every time. I do not recommend it but you could do it if you want:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;Base64,<?=base64_encode(file_get_contents('ftp://username:password@servername.net/image.jpg?_t='.time()));?>">
```

Comment: Well it does show something now, only that I am pretty sure that this is not the image i want it to show.It shows a small square inside of which is what looks like a paper ripped apart in the middle. If it helps, for the above code, it shows the following html: <img src="data:image/jpeg;Base64,">. By the way, I am using firefox as a browser, so after some short research, it seems to be their broken page icon.

Comment: The ripped icon is an error image. There is nothing after the , it means that the image really don't exist. You should check it.